# Comparing two string of equal size with a complexity of O(1) : Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, string, complexity-theory, difference

Basically, I am trying to find the difference between two files which have the same size.

File 1 :

```
Line 1
line 2
line 3
```

File 2 :

```
Line 1
line A
line 3
```

All while keeping a complexity of O(1), i want to know on which line is the difference
If it's not possible what would be the most optimised way to do it ?

Thanks in advance. I have been looking for this for a long time but i still can't find anything that has this level of complexity.

Side note : I am using JS ES6

Comment: `O(1)` is probably impossible. How large are these files?

Comment: Is it possible to compare any length of string in a constant time? Imagine two 10000-length string, only the last character is different. Don't you need to look through first 9999 characters?

Comment: If I could solve this problem in O(1), I wouldn't be sitting here answering questions on SO.

Comment: @JonasWilms log files, it can get pretty big depending on the context.

Answer (score 0):

Say your files each have N lines. Any of those lines might be different, so you will have to read all N lines and compare them. So your complexity has to be at least O(N).

Comment: Ok so let's say i want to just know if there is a difference or not, is it possible on O(1) like using some hash or something and then comparing both hashed files ?

Comment: `if (fileString1 !== fileString2) ...` ;)

Comment: @mplungjan that's O(n) buddy

Comment: It was not meant to be taken seriously unless the files are a few K each

Answer (score 0):

Given two strings `a` and `b` that can be done as:

```
 a = a.split("\n");
 b = b split("\n");
 const line = a.findIndex((line, index) => line !== b[index]);
```

On Nodejs using streams might be more memory wise, but the version above is the simplest.